# Error in defining an std::pair C++17: unmatched constructor

Tags: c++, exception, definition

I'm trying the following definition:

```
std::pair<std::int16_t, std::function<bool()>> urlvaliditypair = std::make_pair(enumIter, &CheckSequence::checkURLValidity);
```

Another associated definition attempt:

```
std::map<std::int16_t, std::function<bool()>> urlvalidityfunc = new std::map<std::int16_t, std::function<bool()>>(enumIter, &CheckSequence::checkURLValidity);
```

where, the function checkURLValidity is defined as:

```
bool CheckSequence::checkURLValidity() { return true; }
```

Kindly point towards what may be the issue with the following compile error:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'pair<typename __make_pair_return<short &>::type, typename __make_pair_return<bool (CheckSequence::*)()>::type>' (aka 'pair<short, bool (conformance::download::CheckSequence::*)()>') to 'std::pair<std::int16_t, std::function<bool ()> > *' (aka 'pair<short, function<bool ()> > *')
            std::pair<std::int16_t, std::function<bool()>> *urlvalidityfunc = std::make_pair(enumIter, &CheckSequence::checkURLValidity);
```

I've tried numerous variations, but what is this error trying to convey? Both std::pair and std::map definitions have an unmatched constructor error. I've tried std::mem_fn too.

The goal is to build a table/map with the iterator and the corresponding method. Please advise.

Comment: If `CheckSequence::checkURLValidity()` is not a `static` member function then this is not a sufficient callable without an instance of `CheckSequence`. Furthermore, I'm not sure whether the implicit conversion from a member function to `std::function` still works with type deduction in `std::make_pair()`. Did you try the explicit construction of the `std::function` instance among your _numerous variations_? Btw. a [mcve] wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Two variations which work (even with type deduction in `std::make_pair()`): [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/748a196372148751)

Comment: @Scheff, thank you for the demo code. Worked with what you suggested. However, a related call still displays an error. While the insert call works with the map, why would the insert_or_assign call complain? Thank you for the indicator regarding the working construct though. Regards

Comment: _While the insert call works with the map, why would the insert_or_assign call complain?_ No idea. It didn't on my side: [**Life Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0de09872851d1654)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `new` is not what you think here. It is not like Java or c# so you don't do:

```
int i = new int(2);
```

its just:

```
int i = 2;
```

Or in your case:

```
std::map<std::int16_t, std::function<bool()>> urlvalidityfunc =
    {{enumIter, &CheckSequence::checkURLValidity}};
```